# What is the statistical test to use for a trend analysis for continuous variables (non-paired)?

Tags: statistical-significance, continuous-data, test-for-trend

Please excuse my very elementary question...
Please see attached graph.  This is an example of the kind of data I'm trying to analyze.  The data points are non-paired.  There is definitely a time-trend, and there are definitely differences between groups.

Any suggestions on which tests are appropriate for (1) differences between group, and (2) time trend?

Any tips will be helpful!  Thank you so much!!!

[image: Example]